# cannot open prog.lua: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, command-line, lua, arguments

This following program converts a text file from windows format to POSIX format(it means that it translates a sequence of carriage return-newlines to newlines)

```
    local inp = assert(io.open(arg[1], "rb"))
    local out = assert(io.open(arg[2], "wb"))

    local data = inp:read("a")
    data = string.gsub(data, "\r\n", "\n")
    out:write(data)

    assert(out:close())
```

Here is the example I want to convert

```
    print("Hello World!")
    print("\r\n")
```

We can call a script form the shell using the format lua [options] [script[args]]. So, I type prog.lua which is the lua file, and the file with the example I want to convert called example.lua so that it gets stored in arg[1] and arg[2]:

```
    >prog.lua exampe.lua example.lua
```

after that I get this error:

```
    C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3\prog.lua:1: bad argument #1 to 'open' (string 
    expected, got nil)
    stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'io.open'
    C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3\prog.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I think that it is inferring to the first argument of the function call in io.open(arg[1], "rb") in the first line. But, I can not understand why it errors since the example file is supposed to be stored in arg[1] and arg[2] but the converter still gives an error. 
Any solutions so that I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Windows feature (or bug).

When Lua is run directly, all arguments `arg1 arg2 arg3` are passed to the script (both inside `arg` table and inside vararg `...`)

```
C:\> lua.exe program.lua arg1 arg2 arg3
```

---

When `.LUA` extension is declared as executable (as in your system), then you can omit `lua.exe` in command line, but the arguments are NOT passed to Lua script.

```
C:\> program.lua arg1 arg2 arg3
```

That's why your `arg[1]` is `nil`.
You have to start your command line with `lua.exe` to pass arguments to your script.

Comment: >lua prog.lua exampe.lua example.lua gives me an error as well: lua: cannot open prog.lua: No such file or directory. If I type lua is it gonna enter interactive mode and the options work though.

Comment: `prog.lua` must be in the current directory. Otherwise, you should specify full path to your program: `lua.exe "C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3\prog.lua" arg1 arg2`

Comment: should I write the full path for arg1 and arg2 as well? prog.lua and example.lua(arg1 and arg2) are in the same directory as the interpreter.

Comment: Full path is required every time the file is not in the current directory.